# No se ejecuta en la línea correcta el System.err

Tags: java, ordenamiento

En este código, la función `System.err.println()` se ejecuta aleatoriamente en la línea que no le corresponde. He leído que hay que usar el `System.err.flush()`, pero no sé muy bien donde utilizarlo ni cuántas veces. He indicado con un comentario la línea que me da problemas. Este es el código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args){           
        //Leer y mostrar por consola el fichero Cliente
        File cliente = new File("Cliente.txt");
        FileReader fileR = null;
        BufferedReader Breader = null;

        try{
            fileR = new FileReader(cliente);
            Breader = new BufferedReader(fileR);
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.err.println("ERROR! No se ha encontrado el archivo " + cliente.getName());
            System.exit(0);
        }

        System.out.println("~~Fichero cliente~~");
        try {
            String lineas = "";
            while((lineas = Breader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(lineas);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Leer y mostrar por consola el fichero Factura
        File factura = new File("Faactura.txt");
        FileReader fileR2 = null;
        BufferedReader Breader2 = null;

        try{
            fileR2 = new FileReader(factura);
            Breader2 = new BufferedReader(fileR2);
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e2){
            /*AQUI FALLA*/ System.err.println("\nERROR! No se ha encontrado el archivo " + factura.getName());
            System.exit(0);
        }

        System.out.println("\n~~Fichero Factura~~");
        try {
            String lineas2 = "";
            while((lineas2 = Breader2.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(lineas2);
            }
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

He escrito adrede "Faactura.txt" en lugar de "Factura.txt" para que salte el System.err que he añadido. La idea es que el texto `ERROR! No se ha encontrado el archivo Faactura.txt` aparezca un salto de línea después de leer el fichero Cliente.txt, y no entre medias.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Varias cuestiones :

- la salida estándar (*STDOUT*, accesible como *System.out* es distinta de la salida de error (*STDERR*, accesible como *System.err*) y son completamente independientes. Pero en una aplicación de consola, ambas acaban mostrándose por defecto en la consola, juntas.
- existen varios niveles de *buffers* de forma que el texto puede que no se muestre inmediatamente al invocar el *println*. Es por eso que te muestra una parte de lo enviado a una salida en medio de texto de otra.
- lo que hace *flush* es vaciar los *buffers* y asegurarse de que se envíen los caracteres almacenados en la salida.

Así que la solución aquí es usar el *flush* de *System.out* antes de escribir por *System.err*.

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar. A veces aparece entre medias y a veces al final (esto es nuevo), pero sin el salto de línea que quería.